# @RetryableTopic in spring boot kafka failing while consuming the record on @DltHandler

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using DelegatingByTopicSerializer and DelegatingByTopicDeserializer in producer and consumer. And also providing the  -> consumerProp.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*"); property. But when any message fails and It try to consume on @DltHandler It's giving exception. Not sure -retry topic is taking the default consumer and producer configuration or not. [Please find the exception details here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRcT5.png)

I tried with other configuration like separate producer and consumer but still facing same issue.